# Can't move to Neo4j 2.2.0 and Spring Data Neo4j 3.3.0.RELEASE

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I use Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE and Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE.
Right now, I can't smoothly move from Neo4j 2.1.7 and SDN 3.2.2.RELEASE to Neo4j 2.2.0 and SDN 3.3.0.RELEASE

First of all, `Neo4jHelper` class is absent... so what should be used instead ?

Also, my tests crashes with a following exceptions:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: nested exception is org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(Neo4jExceptionTranslator.java:51)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
```

but on the previous versions everything work fine(My DAO and Services are annotated with `@Transactional`).

How to configure appropriate TX manager for Neo4j in my Spring Boot application ?

Right now `NullTransactionManager` are used and I think this is a reason of the issue:

```
2015-04-03 11:40:36 [main] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@12db5286: startup date [Fri Apr 03 11:40:36 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-04-03 11:40:37 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2015-04-03 11:40:38 [main] INFO  o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Using JTA UserTransaction: org.springframework.transaction.jta.UserTransactionAdapter@5909b7c2
2015-04-03 11:40:38 [main] INFO  o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Using JTA TransactionManager: org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.NullTransactionManager@16bc4d92
```

what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is work in progress, I have it in a branch but it's not done yet as Neo4j 2.2 changed many internal APIs.

Stay tuned over the next week or so.

Comment: Thanks, will wait for news

Comment: what's the best way to stay alerted to/find out the current status of interoperability between Spring Data/Spring Data Neo4j and Neo4j? Is there a canonical 'status' page anywhere which shows the most recent working combos?

Comment: Filed this JIRA issue a month ago, but so far no response.  I'm guessing that might be the best place to hear about updates when the team has time to do it.  Looking forward to the performance improvements of Neo4j 2.2!
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-593

Comment: Which version of SDN will fix compatibility issues with Neo4j 2.2.* ? Is it SDN 3.4.0 version ?

Comment: Someone filed the duplicate https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-643
and marked it for SDN 3.4.0

Comment: Thanks to Michael Hunger I finally solved this issue in my project with Neo4j 2.2.2 and SDN 3.4.0.M1

Comment: This is fixed in the now-released 3.3.1:
http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/3.3.1.RELEASE/

Comment: @JonathanCrosmer Is this working for you? 2.2.0 seems to suffer the NotInTransactionException and from 2.2.1 the QueryNotPossibleException.class seems to have been moved out of the neo4j-lucene-index jar.

Comment: @JonathanCrosmer and then I found this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-691 so I guess the answer to my question is "not out of the box".

Comment: @JohnMark13 We had multiple issues with upgrading to Neo4j 2.2.x series against SDN 3.3.1, even though it is supposedly supported.  The link you posted was one of them, which I was able to work around.  We also tried Neo4j 2.2.0 but it seemed unstable, even corrupting our database on restart, plus it seems irresponsible to use an earlier-than-latest micro release.  Once we had 2.2.3 embedded running, it seemed to have some serious stability problems, including mysteriously crashing our JVM process.  Since 2.1.8 seems stable, and we were running out of dev time, we went with that (for now).

Comment: I don't know if the stability issues were due to Neo4j or Spring Data.  When we reverted to Neo4j 2.1.8 with no other code changes, our everything seemed to work.