# No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _)

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

**Spring data neo4j version: 3.3.0.RELEASE**
**Neo4j version: 2.2.2**

I ran into the following exception when I tried to query default methods exposed on a spring-data repository i.e.

```
personRepository.findAll(getDefaultPageable());

public static Pageable getDefaultPageable() {
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Pageable> biFunction = PageRequest::new; // Method reference syntax in action
    return biFunction.apply(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _) 
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:40)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:36)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.getDefaultedTypeToBeUsed(DefaultTypeMapper.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:142)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.projectTo(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:216)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.projectTo(Neo4jTemplate.java:241)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.doConvert(EntityResultConverter.java:73)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.convert(DefaultConverter.java:44)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.convert(EntityResultConverter.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1.underlyingObjectToObject(QueryResultBuilder.java:86)
>       at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IterableWrapper$MyIteratorWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(IterableWrapper.java:57)
>       at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.subList(AbstractGraphRepository.java:371)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.extractPage(AbstractGraphRepository.java:355)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.findAll(AbstractGraphRepository.java:321)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:414)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:399)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.findAll(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.findAll(Unknown Source)

I am really not trying to do anything complicated here so I'm struggling to understand if I should really introduce a custom query with underscore prefixed labels and use the annotation @Query for it? Don't the default methods from Spring data just work on SDN?

---

### ## UPDATE ##

**I adapted the cypher query and still ended up with the same error**.

> used by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _) 
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:40)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:36)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.getDefaultedTypeToBeUsed(DefaultTypeMapper.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:142)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.createEntityFromState(Neo4jTemplate.java:224)

Can you please take a look at the classes and let me know where and what I'm doing incorrectly?

Here's the repository class

```
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person>, CypherDslRepository<Person> {
String PERSONS_WITH_SEVERAL_ACME_IDENTITY = "MATCH (p:Person)-[r:HAS_LOGIN]->(a:AcmeIdp) " +
        "SET p:_Person, a:_AcmeIdp "+
        "WITH p, count(p) AS numoutgoing " +
        "WHERE numoutgoing > 1 " +
        "MATCH (p:Person)-[r:HAS_LOGIN]->(a:AcmeIdp) " +
        "SET p:_Person, a:_AcmeIdp "+
        "RETURN p";

Iterable<Person> findByFirstNameAndLastName(@NonNull final String firstName,@NonNull final String lastName);

Page<Person> findByFirstNameLike(@NonNull final String firstName,@NonNull final Pageable pageable);

@Query(PERSONS_WITH_SEVERAL_ACME_IDENTITY)
Page<Person> findOnesWithSeveralAcmeIdentities(@NonNull final Pageable pageable); }
```

The person entity class

```
import com.example.analytics.model.AbstractEntity;
import com.example.analytics.model.relationship.Login;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Set;

@NodeEntity(useShortNames = true)
public class Person extends AbstractEntity {

    @GraphProperty(propertyName = "title", defaultValue = "")
    private String title;

    @GraphProperty(propertyName = "firstName", defaultValue = "")
    private String firstName;

    @GraphProperty(propertyName = "lastName", defaultValue = "")
    private String lastName;

    @GraphProperty(propertyName = "dateOfBirth", propertyType = String.class)
    private LocalDateTime dateOfBirth;

    @RelatedTo(type = "HAS_LOGIN", direction = Direction.OUTGOING, elementClass = AcmeIdentity.class)
    private Set<Login> logins;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(final String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(final String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(final LocalDateTime dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public Set<Login> getLogins() {
        return logins;
    }

    public void setLogins(@NonNull final Set<Login> logins) {
        this.logins = logins;
    }
}
```

The converter

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Component
public class LocalDateTimeToStringConverter implements Converter<LocalDateTime, String> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocalDateTimeToStringConverter.class);

    @Value("${neo4j.dateTime.format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")
    private String dateTimeFormat;

    @Override
    public String convert(@NonNull final LocalDateTime source) {
        LOG.debug("Converting LocalDateTime into String using the format: {}", dateTimeFormat);
        return String.valueOf(source.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat)));
    }

}
```

The reverse converter

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Component
public class StringToLocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StringToLocalDateTimeConverter.class);

    @Value("${neo4j.dateTime.format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")
    private String dateTimeFormat;

    /**
     * Convert the source of type S to target type T.
     *
     * @param source the source object to convert, which must be an instance of S (never {@code null})
     * @return the converted object, which must be an instance of T (potentially {@code null})
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the source could not be converted to the desired target type
     */
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(@NonNull final String source) {
        LOG.debug("Converting String {} into LocalDateTime using the format: {}",source, dateTimeFormat);
        return LocalDateTime.parse(source, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat));
    }

}
```

The Main configuration class

```
import com.example.analytics.converter.LocalDateTimeToStringConverter;
import com.example.analytics.converter.StringToLocalDateTimeConverter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.analytics"})
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
@Import({DatabaseConnectionConfiguration.class})
public class MainConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private StringToLocalDateTimeConverter stringToLocalDateTimeConverter;

    @Autowired
    private LocalDateTimeToStringConverter localDateTimeToStringConverter;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainConfiguration.class);

    public MainConfiguration() {
        setBasePackage("com.example.analytics.model");
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({ "stringToLocalDateTimeConverter", "localDateTimeToStringConverter" })
    protected ConversionService neo4jConversionService() throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("Adding custom converters to conversion service ...");
        ConversionService conversionService = super.neo4jConversionService();
        ConverterRegistry registry = (ConverterRegistry) conversionService;
        registry.addConverter(stringToLocalDateTimeConverter);
        registry.addConverter(localDateTimeToStringConverter);
        LOG.debug("Addition of Converter from LocalDateTime to String and vice-versa has been completed!");
        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

Snippet of the service using the repository

```
public Page<Person> findPersonsWithSeveralAcmeIdentitites(final Pageable pageable) {
    LOG.debug("Fetching persons with several ACME identities");

    if(pageable != null)
        return personRepository.findOnesWithSeveralAcmeIdentities(pageable);
   else 
        return personRepository.findOnesWithSeveralAcmeIdentities(getDefaultPageable());

}
```

Comment: SDN 3.3.0 doesn't work with 2.2.2 yet

Comment: How did you create the data?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks for your reply.

I created data by importing a CSV file and added additional data into my local instance by using graphgen tool. 

Which version of SDN or Neo4j should I use?  Is there a compatibility table available somewhere that indicates the version of SDN for a version of Neo4j?

Comment: SDN 3.3.0 is incompatible with Neo4j2.2.2 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418188/cant-move-to-neo4j-2-2-0-and-spring-data-neo4j-3-3-0-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You then have to go over your nodes and on each of them call:

```
neo4jTemplate.postEntityCreation(node, MyEntity.class);
```

Alternatively this should work too:

```
MATCH (n:User) set n:_User;
```

etc.

**I think you're overdoing Java8 method references !!! Just use plain old `new`. Otherwise your code will be unmaintainable going forward.**

```
public static Pageable getDefaultPageable() {
    return new PageRequest(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael. I'll try and use the Neo4j template and let you know my findings. If I understand you correctly, an upgrade isn't necessary in my case; right?

I am preparing a prototype that would demonstrate features of Neo4j and Java 8 so that it can adopted by the organisation for which I work; which is precisely why you witness method references even though they're redundant.

Comment: I notice, the method 
[public <S extends org.neo4j.graphdb.PropertyContainer,T> void postEntityCreation(S node,Class<T> entityClass)] (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.4.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/Neo4jTemplate.html#postEntityCreation-S-java.lang.Class-) is **deprecated**

Comment: What does the method 
public <S extends org.neo4j.graphdb.PropertyContainer,T> void postEntityCreation(S node, Class<T>entityClass) 
actually do? The method intentionally has **NO documentation!**