# Neo4j 2.2.3 server fails to start when database is created using Spring Data Neo4J 3.3.1

Tags: java, spring, maven, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have followed this [guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_spring_data_environment_setup.htm) when creating a Spring Data Neo4j application.

I have included:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

In my ***pom.xml***

When trying to start the server I get the following error:

> "Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start."

The message log says:

> "Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase"

I have read that the Spring Data Neo4j and the Neo4j server versions might not be compatible with each other.

**Question: How can I know which versions are compatible?**

**Stacktrace:**

```
2015-07-09 13:03:56.231+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Shutdown started
2015-07-09 13:03:56.244+0000 ERROR [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase]: Failed to start database.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\neo4j
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:335) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:44) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:110) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:203) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.desktop.runtime.DatabaseActions.start(DatabaseActions.java:71) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.desktop.ui.StartDatabaseActionListener$1.run(StartDatabaseActionListener.java:61) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager@5a7c7505' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:331) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@50f074ae' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:117) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UpgradingStoreVersionNotFoundException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' does not contain a store version, please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:86) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:158) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:259) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:134) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:564) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:460) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
... 27 common frames omitted
2015-07-09 13:03:56.244+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer]: Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
```

Comment: Did you shut down your Spring App before starting the Neo4j server? You can't access the store-files from two different processes.

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace.

Comment: Added the stacktrace

Comment: And the Spring App does not run when starting the Neo4j server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the problem by closing the stream as stated by Michael Hunger (misunderstood what was meant by shutting down the spring app).

I.e.

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml");
context.close();

Comment: You were successful in starting Neo4j 2.2.3 with Spring Data 3.3.1?  I ran into a ClassNotFoundException, and it seemed to be caused by SDN code...
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-691
I thought it was an incompatible version.  However if you were successful then perhaps my issue was something else.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently not a central list that shows Spring Data Neo4j compatibility with Neo4j versions.  That would be very helpful though, as when incompatible versions are used SDN tends to throw strange exceptions, e.g.
[Can't move to Neo4j 2.2.0 and Spring Data Neo4j 3.3.0.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418188/cant-move-to-neo4j-2-2-0-and-spring-data-neo4j-3-3-0-release)